# RegEx get highlited text C#

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

i'am trying to get from this text:

```
updateServer
cInterface_test-184
cServer_test-184
dControl_test-178
mcontrol_doorinterface_test-178
```

the italic strings. Eg in second line *test-184* i'am using the following regEx:

```
test+.*
```

But how can i extract the *test-184* in a string in c# wpf ?

Thanks :)

EDIT: The Stars are not in the Text, I wanted to highlight the text i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 'test-', is there always a number?

If so, the following is the best for you:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"
updateServer
cInterface_*test-184*
cServer_*test-184*
dControl_*test-178*
mcontrol_doorinterface_*test-178*
";
            var pattern = @"test-\d*";

            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
                        Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

If 'test-' is not a constant, you can use the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"
updateServer
cInterface_*test-184*cServer_*test-184*
cServer_*test-184*
dControl_*test-178*
mcontrol_doorinterface_*test-178*
";
            var pattern = @"\*(.*?)\*";

            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Work's fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use code llke this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = @"
updateServer
cInterface_*test-184*
cServer_*test-184*
dControl_*test-178*
mcontrol_doorinterface_*test-178*
";
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, "\\*(.*)\\*"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to turn (.*) in non-greedy (.*?). It will work even if the values are in a single line, like: cInterface_*test-184*cServer_*test-184*

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
That's it